# How to pass the parameter "this" in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way I can pass the parameter value "this" in HTML, where "this" refers to the object it is loaded in. Something like:

```
<div onload="floatIn(this)">
    <p>test</p>
</div>
```

Where `function= floatIn(element){//}` so the element should be the div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"onload" event is meant for elements requiring fetching of their contents, e.g. images; therefore the event won't be triggered for `div` elements.
If you want to trigger script after div was rendered you have to run  after `div` is mentioned in HTML:

```html
<script>
  function floatIn(div) {
    console.log(div);
  }
</script>


<div id="mydiv">
  <p>test</p>
</div>
<script>
  var div = document.getElementById('mydiv');
  floatIn(div);
</script>
```

But if you have images inside your div the callback defined this way will be triggered after div is rendered, but before the images has loaded. To handle such a situation you have to listen to images 'load' event (e.g. see [this jQuery library](https://imagesloaded.desandro.com/)).

**UPDATE:** you can create your own callback attribute if you want to and have permissions to append the script:

```html
<div id="div1" onrender="this.textContent = this.id"></div>
<div id="div2" onrender="this.textContent = this.id"></div>

<!-- ...and the end of the document -->
<script>
  document.querySelectorAll('[onrender]').forEach(function (elem) {
    var func = new Function(elem.getAttribute('onrender'));
    func.call(elem);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: yeah okay i already thougt that i have to do that , that way. I hoped that there was a way , i had not to specify div = document.getElementById('mydiv') but could just write "this" for the element , where the function is loaded.

Comment: @MaestroD unfortunately there's no attribute which allows you to run a callback on div rendering.

If you really want to do this (and have permissions to append script to the end) you can create your own attribute for the callback: https://jsfiddle.net/brujx057/5/

Answer (score 0):

The only thing special about the `this` variable is how it is defined.

You can pass its value just like any other variable when you call a function.

---

Your problem here is that a `div` element doesn't have a `load` event because it isn't loading anything, so your event handler will never fire (and your HTML is invalid).

Comment: So do i have always to call the div directly with document.getElementby.... or is there another way , similar to the "this"? Or shall i do that with an eventlistener?